# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-960ab8_b/psycopg2/

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I get this error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-960ab8_b/psycopg2/
```

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

While trying to deploy AWS lambda,

Requirement file includes:

```
requests

psycopg2
```

This issue is on Mac, Python 3.7.3, pip 19.1.

Could you please suggest a solution ?

Command : sls deploy

Here is the full trace of the error:

Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
Serverless: Running docker run --rm -v /Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/.serverless/requirements:/var/task:z -u 0 lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 python3.6 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt...

Error --------------------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-378xq3gn/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

```
 For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

Error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-378xq3gn/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

```
at filterCommands.forEach (/Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:303:13)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at installRequirements (/Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:290:28)
at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:515:3)
at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:594:29)
```

From previous event:
    at Object.before [as hook] (/Users/sowmyalakkegowda/Desktop/shipamax/routing/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/index.js:171:10)
    at BbPromise.reduce (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:372:55)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)

Comment: show full traceback as well as the command that led to this error please

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Adding version number to package psycopg2==2.7.4 solved this issue